# "Job Role" section Interactive Form

Tags: javascript

Can you tell me what's wrong with this code below?

```
var jobItem = document.querySelectorAll('#title');
var fieldset = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset');

var other = document.getElementById('other');
other.style.display = '';// this one is the error
```

the instruction asked is to:

The "Job Role" section has an `<input type="text">` field where users can enter a custom job role. If the user selects "Other" in the "Job Role" drop down menu, they can enter info into the "Other job role" text field. But this field should be hidden by default and only displayed once users select "Other" in the drop down menu, and be hidden if the user selects any other option.

Hide the "text field" with the id of "other-job-role" so it is not displayed when the form first loads.
Program the "Job Role" `<select>` element to listen for user changes. When a change is detected, display/hide the "text field" based on the user’s selection in the drop down menu.

Comment: What error is reported? Where's your HTML? Please, take the time to read both the "*[ask]*' and "*[mcve]*" guidance. Currently, without more information, we can't possibly help without guessing, which is of little too use to you and of no help to any future visitors to the site that may have similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

To hide an element set the `display` property to `none` rather than leaving it empty.

```
other.style.display = 'none';
```